# Windows 11 shared folder does't accept credentials

Tags: windows

I have 2 computers with windows 11. One of the share a folder and in this folder I have one user that has permissions to access the folder and also is an allowed user to can access as shared resource.

From the second computer, I have tried to access to this folder. The user in the second computer is another user different from the second computer and in the past, when I wanted to access, I use the credentials of the user of the first computer and I could access.

But from one ago more or less, I get the error that the user don't have permissions to access.

I have check the permissions in the first  computer, and the user has the permission, both permissions, file system and network.

I have tried to create another user in the first computer, that has the user name and password than the user of the second computer in which I am trying to access. In this case I can access.

I don't want in the first computer to have to add a user that has the same user and password than in the second computer, I would like to can access just writing the credentials, because if I have many computers from which I want to access to first computer, I have to add all the users.

Really I don't modify any configuration in the first computer and I don't know why I could access just only writing the credentials until one week ago than I can't.

There is some change in windows that modify the behavior of shared folders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something went wrong with the credentials that Windows remembers
for that share.

Try to delete all remembered credential(s) to the share, so that when
connecting to it, Windows will ask again for the credentials to use:

- Run *Start > Credential Manager*
- Position to "Windows Credentials"
- Search for any credentials to your share
- For each found credential, click the down-arrow on its right and
  select Remove.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help.

In my second computer (from which I try to access), I only have some few generic credentials, but none of them are related with my first computer.

Comment: I have realize than from another computer I can access as usual, but I can't access from my computer. Also I have tried another user account in this computer and the problem is the same. So it seems the problem is with that computer, no matter the user.

Comment: Have you considered that the problem lies in some difference between the two computers? For example, if one uses Windows local account and the other a Microsoft account.

Comment: In both computers I am using local account. Also the other account from which have tried is administrator account.

Comment: By all that you have said, this should work. There must be some setting or product that is interfering, on the server side or on your side. Perhaps the permissions have somehow changed, or something else.

Comment: I delete all certificates in my user (no administrator user), so I guess this is not the problem. But perhaps there is some other network configuration or data that I could clear or delete to reset the network congfiguration, but I don't know.